# Import/export large mysql databases

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

**Which scripts/solutions do use for import and export large mysql databases?**

Phpmyadmin gives an error for these operations, if there is a big amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sypex.net/en/ is better than Phpmyadmin in that

Comment: may be, I haven't seen it for a while.

Comment: @WorkingHard not known to me. I'd go for mysqldump then

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the command line in both locations, [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html)

For more verbose answers, you'll need to add much more information about your setup, e.g. whether you are on some sort of hosting package or a server of your own.

Comment: virtual hosting and localhost.

Comment: Even with a virtual host, you should be able to SSH into the server if it is set up.

Comment: @judda, its a redundant solution

Comment: @WorkingHard I don't understand what you mean by that? Anyway, if you have command line access, `mysqldump` to export and `mysql` to import will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

Using phpmyadmin is pointless for large databases. As of yet I have been using databases just over 1 GB in size, with over 12 million records. In my experience, the best way to export data is to use

```
mysqldump -h HOST -u USER -p database_name > export_file.sql
```

-h is optional in most cases. If you are on a remote server and the error "mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user..." pops up, add --single-transaction;

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -h HOST -u USER -p database_name > export_file.sql
```

You can look up the reason [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html). To import the database you can use

```
mysql -h HOST -u USER -p database_name < export_file.sql
```